# AttributeError for QTabWidget Triangular in PySide6

Tags: python, pyside6

I'm encountering an issue while running example code using PySide6. The error is AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QTabWidget' object has no attribute 'Triangular'. The problematic code snippet is

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget,QTabWidget

class TabDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabDemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "Page 0")
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(1,self.tab2, "Page 1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab3, "Page 2")
        # source code
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(self.tabWidget.Triangular)
        # right code
        # self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Triangular)
        # self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QTabWidget.TabShape.Triangular)
        self.resize(300,400)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = TabDemo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

``.

When I modify it to `self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Triangular)` or `self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QTabWidget.TabShape.Triangular)`, it works fine.

I have two questions: First, why can't access the 'Triangular' attribute through an instance, and second, why is it possible to access QTabWidget.Triangular directly using the class name?

I just modify the code to `self.tabWidget.setTabShape(self.tabWidget.TabShape.Triangular)`,and it also works.

Comment: Does `self.tabWidget.TabShape.Triangular` work?

Comment: Ok, that works. So why QTabWidget.Triangular can work?

Comment: Since Qt6, both PyQt and PySide introduced actual Enum (instead of the old int types), which has the consequence of requiring full namespaces. With PySide they choose to provide a "forgiveness mode" that still allows using the old syntax (which is completely deprecated in PyQt6), but, apparently, it only works for class attributes, not instance ones. It could be a bug, but considering that they will probably remove that forgiveness mode sooner or later, I don't think it would be worth reporting.